# Странная ошибка vk_api python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

начал учиться писать ботов для вк на python, сделал простую ерунду, но она выдает ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста, как её исправить.
Код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

token = 'token'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
def sender(text):
    vk_session.metod('message.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to.me:

            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id

            if msg == 'привет':
                sender(id, 'ахахахахахах фу я тебе не отвечу')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/йцу/Documents/PythonProjects/vkbot.py", line 8, in <module>
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
  File "C:\Users\йцу\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 517, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "C:\Users\йцу\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 531, in update_longpoll_server
    response = self.vk.method('messages.getLongPollServer', values)
  File "C:\Users\йцу\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [5] User authorization failed: invalid session.
```

Comment: Ну а что вы ожидали: sender(id, 'ахахахахахах фу я тебе не отвечу'). Бот не отвечает, вы же сами хотели.

Comment: классная шутка)

Comment: `User authorization failed: invalid session.` - VK ругается на сессию. Проверяйте токен, и все что связано с авториазцией.